# Issue with Local Storage and Pixel Swapping in p5.js Sliding Puzzle Game

Tags: javascript, sorting, local-storage, p5.js

I'm currently working on a sliding puzzle game using p5.js, and I'm encountering an issue with the save and load functionality using local storage. The game saves the last location of pixels as an array with 2500 arguments. When attempting to swap pixel locations based on this array during the load operation, some unexpected multiplication seems to occur.

To illustrate the problem, let's consider a two-argument array, a = [1, 2], representing the initial pixel positions. The goal is to change the pixel locations to b = [2, 1]. However, during the swap operation, the pixel values get multiplied, resulting in an array like [2, 2] instead of the desired [2, 1].

Here's a snippet of the code where the issue arises:

```
 


if (key === 'W' || key === 'w') {
    
    initializeFlag = true;

    const savedPixelGuide = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pixelGuide'));
    const randomPiece = pieces[shuffledArray[zer+14]];
    const shuffledPiece = shufflePixels(randomPiece, 42);
    
    for (let j = 0; j < savedPixelGuide.length; j++) {
      let index1 = savedPixelGuide[j];
      let sourceIndex = index1 * 4;
      
      let targetIndex = j * 4;
      
      shuffledPiece.pixels[targetIndex] = shuffledPiece.pixels[sourceIndex];
      shuffledPiece.pixels[targetIndex + 1] = shuffledPiece.pixels[sourceIndex + 1];
      shuffledPiece.pixels[targetIndex + 2] = shuffledPiece.pixels[sourceIndex + 2];
      shuffledPiece.pixels[targetIndex + 3] = shuffledPiece.pixels[sourceIndex + 3];
}
    
    shuffledPiece.updatePixels(); // Corrected: Added parentheses to call the function
    
    resizedPiece = resizeImage(shuffledPiece, DIM, DIM);
    
  setTimeout(() => {
    initializeFlag = false;
  }, 1);
  return;
  }
```

I'm struggling to identify why this unexpected multiplication is happening during the pixel swap. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried multiple approaches but the final visual remain same.

Comment: What is the actual content of `savedPixelGuide`? Can you enhance your code by a striped-down dataset of e.g. 100 entries which shows your issue?

Comment: The location of the changed pixels. They are numerical values ​​containing numbers between 0-2499. The original array is sequentially starting from 0 and ending at 2499. SavedPixelGuide is a mangled version of this array, and I call it in code with a for loop for the canvas.